# Swiftui: passing interpolated string with Image into Text view as String doesn't show Image given

Tags: swiftui

when i pass an interpolated string with Image into a Text view, it returns incorrectly.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct UserMediaCell: View {
    var body: some View {
        subView(label:"\(Image(systemName: "ellipsis"))") 
        // shows incorrectly:
        // Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<SwiftUI.Image.(unknown context at $18c350410).NamedImageProvider>)

        Text("\(Image(systemName: "ellipsis"))") 
        // shows correctly. (sf symbol visible)
    }
}

struct subView: View {
    @State var label: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(label)
    }
}
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: Are you planning to always use an SF Font as part of the label? If so, simply pass the name of the SF Font image and use it in the subView as Text("\(Image(systemName: whateverFontYouPass)) this will be additional text") or if you are only using an SF Font, Image(systemName: whateverFontYouPass)

Comment: You should read this article: https://linuxtut.com/en/d9b0fdadec8ca77a556c/

Comment: @Yrb the subView will use accept both strings and images mixed, thats why I did it this way, thanks for the help either ways!

Comment: @RajaKishan that seems helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because your subview is taking the result of the string interpolation as a String type. Where the Text view that is working correctly is not using a String to initialize the view, but a Localized String Key.

Change your subview to account for that like so:

```swift
// Structs, Classes, and Actors should start with a Capital Letter BTW
struct SubView: View {
    @State var label: LocalizedStringKey

    var body: some View {
        Text(label)
    }
}
```